# Bootstrap 3: How to align my header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a simple header like so:

[image]

Here's my bare bones code:
http://www.ogmda.com/test/help.html

I just can't seem to get the LOGO, NAV, and SOCIAL ICONS items to float correctly using BS3's baked in code. Can someone help start me on the right foot? How would you write the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the following seems to do it for me:

```
h1 { float: left; }
.list-inline { text-align: right; }
.nav-pils { float: right }
```

Comment: This works good, however, when I do the .nav-pills li {float: right}, it causes the nav menu to reverse itself (like so: CONTACT US, NEWS, ABOUT US, CONTRACTS, CAREERS, CAPABILITIES, HOME instead of HOME, CAPABILITIES, CAREERS...). How to fix?